# How to get a prompt to save unsaved changes when logging out/rebooting/shutting down Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot, logout, prompt

Say, I open gedit, type something, click restart, and just lose everything I have typed.. And it seems to be the case not only for gedit.. So, how can I make Ubuntu to ask me whether I want to save changes every time before logging out/rebooting/shutting down?